# state mapping / enum mapping

Tags: enums, mapping, enumeration

I have an enumeration:

```
public enum Process
{

 visiblestateA = 1,
 visiblestateB = 2,
 visiblestateC = 3,
 visiblestateD = 4
 ...
}
```

This enumeration is the visible state of a process. The process itself has 6 subprocesses with 6 subprocess states

```
public enum Subprocess1
{ 

 subprocess1stateA = 1,
 subprocess1stateB = 2,
 subprocess1stateC = 3,
 subprocess1stateD = 4
 ...
}

public enum Subprocess2 { ... }
public enum Subprocess3 { ... }
public enum Subprocess4 { ... }
public enum Subprocess5 { ... }
public enum Subprocess6 { ... }
```

I am looking for a good way to map Process <-> Subprocess

this would be a solution

```
if (_subprocess1 == Subprocess1.subprocess1stateA  && _subprocess3 == Subprocess3.subprocess3stateD)
_process = Process.visiblestateA;
```

How can i create a mapping like this thats works in both direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a state mapping table in the database and get the states both direction with 2 procedures.